# How to iterate through a list of lists

Tags: r

I want to iterate through a list of lists (in a dataframe) so that for each Biopsy site I add a random number, apart from if Biopsy site: None in which case no paste happens

***Input:***

```
list(c("Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb", "Biopsy site: Stomach", 
"Biopsy site: None", "Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum"
), "Biopsy site: None", c("Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum", 
"Biopsy site: Stomach", "Biopsy site: Oesophagus"), c("Biopsy site: Stomach", 
"Biopsy site: None", "Biopsy site: Oesophagus"), c("Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb", 
"Biopsy site: Stomach"))
```

***Intended output***

```
[1] "3 Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb"             "5 Biopsy site: Stomach"                   "Biopsy site: None"                      "7 Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum"

[[2]]
[1] "Biopsy site: None"

[[3]]
[1] "8 Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum" "3 Biopsy site: Stomach"                   "7 Biopsy site: Oesophagus"               

[[4]]
[1] "6 Biopsy site: Stomach"    "Biopsy site: None"       "3 Biopsy site: Oesophagus"

[[5]]
[1] "2 Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb" "3 Biopsy site: Stomach"
```

***Attempted***

```
    lapply(OGDProcedureDf$BiopsyType, function(p)
ifelse(!grepl("None",OGDProcedureDf$BiopsyType),paste(sample(1:10),OGDProcedureDf$BiopsyType),"")
        )
```

but I think the problem is that this is a nested list so I need nested `lapply` ?

Comment: `5 Biopsy site: Stomach` <-- I don't see this data in your source vector.

Comment: @TimBeigeleisen its number two in the first element of the outer list above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No nested lapply is necessary , and you're attempt is pretty close actually:

```
lst_0 <- list(c("Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb", "Biopsy site: Stomach", 
"Biopsy site: None", "Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum"
), "Biopsy site: None", c("Biopsy site: D2 - 2nd part of duodenum", 
"Biopsy site: Stomach", "Biopsy site: Oesophagus"), c("Biopsy site: Stomach", 
"Biopsy site: None", "Biopsy site: Oesophagus"), c("Biopsy site: Duodenal bulb", 
"Biopsy site: Stomach"))

lapply(lst_0, function(p)
  ifelse(!grepl("None",p),paste(sample(1:10),p),p)
)
```